# Redirecting multiple duplicate URLs to main URL using .htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, web-development-server, filezilla

I developed a website and from SEO point of view, the homepage of a website is available under three or more different URLs which accordingly poses a risk of duplicate content, since the same content can be accessed via different URLs.

for eg.
my website is opening with below URL

```
https://www.insider.in/index.php

https://www.insider.in/

https://insider.in/
```

Exact URL which is needed be like

```
https://www.insider.in/
```

for achieving the same i am using an .htaccess file with code given below:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*index\.(php|html?)[#?]?
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.(php|html?)$ https://insider.in/$1[R=301,L]
```

I tried to redirect all duplicate URLs to one URL using the above .htaccess file code but it is not working, also i enabled all the file permissions in FileZilla but again no success.

Any help or reference will be appreciated, thankyou!

note- website is hosted in cloud server using FileZilla

for Reference I am sharing the screenshots

[Image of development folder for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1beW.png)

[Image of .htaccess rule which i have used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsDb8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rules below to fix duplicate content issues on your site :

```
 RewriteEngine on

#Redirect non-www domain to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^insider\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.insider.in%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
 #Redirect /index.php to /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.insider.in/ [L,R=301]
```

Remember to put theses rules at the top of your htaccess.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response,  I just tried the above reference code but issue did not resolved.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response,  I just tried the above reference code but issue did not resolved, same problem still persist, redirection not working

Comment: @Sameer try clearing your browser cache or try a different browser to test the rules.

Comment: Hello @Amit Verma, Thanks for your response, as per your recommendation, i tried clearing cache, also tried it in incognito mode and in different browser also but did'nt worked

Comment: Is there a possibility that there might be some issue from server side or in FileZilla ?

Comment: @Sameer FileZilla has nothing to do with this issue. The problem might be elsewhere. Do you have any other rules ,directives or client side redirects that can conflict with the code I provided above?

Comment: Hello @Amit Verma, i have shared the screenshot for your reference, can you please check those